# wget stuck in "HTTP request sent, awaiting response..." and curl as well

Tags: curl, wget

I'm trying to download a web page and store it locally to html file. I tried with wget (with hand without user agent):

```
wget -r -l1 -U "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686 (x86_64)) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.75 Safari/537.36"  https://www.hipercor.es/supermercado/0110120952600649-lays-gourmet-patatas-fritas-crujientes-original-sin-gluten-180-g/
```

but it got stuck to awaiting response...
Then I tried with curl, but I got:

```
curl -V www.hipercor.es/supermercado/0110120952600649-lays-gourmet-patatas-fritas-crujientes-original-sin-gluten-180-g
curl 7.54.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin18.0) libcurl/7.54.0 LibreSSL/2.6.4 zlib/1.2.11 nghttp2/1.24.1
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz HTTP2 UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy
```

Any reason why it fails on this particular page? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I used this line and it worked for me. I also had user and password for authentication which I passed as usual `--user` and `--password` args.

`wget -U ‘Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.27 Safari/537.17’ YOUR_LINK`

reference link: https://medium.com/@ayrusreev/wget-not-working-on-some-pages-307846b7941d

Comment: Could you explain the difference with Peppe's command line? What made it work? Is it removing -r or changing -U (or adding credentials)? The reference seems to indicate it's -U... but I cannot make it work here.